# pick the elements INSIDE the ul NOT the ul itself

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

this is the php code:

```
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('URL');
$elem = $html->find('ul[id=members-list]', 0);
echo $elem;
```

I would like to be able to pick the inside of the UL so the elements per se, not the ul itself.
html as follows:

```
<ul id="members-list">
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
</ul>
```

so when I do `echo $elem` it returns the ul included. I want to take it out just return :

```
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
```

Comment: Why is this question tagged with curl and jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just forgot to use `children()` method. Consider this example:

```
$ul = $html->find('ul[id="members-list"]', 0)->children();
foreach($ul as $li) {
    echo $li;
}
```

Is stated in the [manual](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm):

**`How to traverse the DOM tree? -> Traverse the DOM Tree`**

**`mixed$e->children ( [int $index] ) Returns the Nth child object if index is set, otherwise return an array of children.`**

Or the much easier way: **`->innertext`** magic attribute

```
$ul = $html->find('ul[id="members-list"]', 0);
echo $ul->innertext;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$('#members-list li')
```

to iterate over them:

```
$('#members-list li').each(function(){
   console.log(this);//object of current li
});
```

Comment: thank you! but that's jquery how to select it with simple html dom ?

Comment: based on your code you can use `$elem = $html->find('ul[id=members-list li]', 0);`

Comment: that didnt work, this $html->find('ul[id=members-list]', 0); works but add the li and it returns nothing

Comment: can you share the fiddle with rendered dom

Comment: how do I put php in a fiddle

Comment: sorry but i am not familiar with php code. this is jquery selector

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this this also will print the values of inside **li** tag

```
<?php

 $html = file_get_contents('2.html');
 $dom = new DOMDocument;
 $dom->loadHTML($html);
 foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('ul') as $node) {
       foreach($node->childNodes as $childNode){
           echo $childNode->nodeValue;
       }
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `.html()` for the selected `ul` element :

```
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('URL');
$elem = $html->find('ul[id=members-list]', 0)->html();
                                               ^-- to get all child elements with tag
echo $elem;
```

Comment: I am trying to NOT take the ul. :)

Comment: but this will return what is inside ul and not ul